# Deploying a CodeRush plugin from the Community Site

Tags: devexpress, coderush

If I have a plugin that I want to deploy from the DevExpress CodeRush Community site, how do I deploy it onto my machine?

[This one looks like such a useful plugin](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/DX_ReviseSelection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How do I install a plugin**

Instructions are linked to, from the top of each plugin page. 
Look for the blue button that says "Install help" (**[Also linked here](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/InstallInstructions)**)

Essentially all you have to do is **drop the dll in the right directory** and **restart studio.**

**Issues**

One potential issue surrounds the idea that dlls built on machines other than your own, are not inherently trusted by your machine and therefore will not always be loaded until they have been unblocked. (A one time exercise per dll at most)

Travis Illig has [some information on how to deal with this situation](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/05/19/unblocking-multiple-files-at-once.aspx).

Comment: A comment about the http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/InstallInstructions page ... ensure your Options settings are not set to 'New User'

Answer (score 1):

Top Menu - DevExpress - Community Plug-Ins... - Past link in URL: Combo - Get Plug-in

Answer (score 1):

Since the 11.2 release, IDE Tools includes a [special VSIX DXCore plug-in project template](http://www.skorkin.com/2011/10/deploying-dxcore-coderush-or-community-plug-ins-using-a-vsix-extension/#.TsGuj3Ei6Hk) that allows you to create a usual DXCore plug-in and deploy it through an Extension to the Visual Studio IDE.