# Removing a CodeRush Community plugin

Tags: devexpress, coderush

In this question - [Deploying a CodeRush plugin from the Community Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597725/deploying-a-coderush-plugin-from-the-community-site) - I asked about deploying a CodeRush plugin from the Community Site.

I deployed the plugin, and created a key binding.

I've had some inspiration, and want to create a similar plugin with a different name, and a different key-binding, but I now want to remove this plugin.

What steps do I need to take to remove it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. From the **DevExpress** menu, select "**About...**".
2. **Shift+Click** the "**Plug-ins...**" button. This opens the **Community** plug-in folder and the **CodeRush** plug-in folder. Shift+Clicking the button saves you a step and closes the About box for you.
3. Find the plug-in you want to remove and delete it (or move it to another location). If the plug-in is locked you will need to close down any instances of VS that have loaded the plug-in and then try again.

Comment: Mark, you get a plus 1, for the Shift-Button click to open the Community plugins folder so easily. But unfortunately you get a minus 1 for making it obscure and not discoverable. So that cancels it out. ;)

Comment: cometbill: And thus illustrating the ongoing tension between discoverability and efficiency.